# Animation TextField Is Gone in Swift

Tags: swift3, swift4

please i have an question about why when i set the animation for the textfield bounds property the animation is gone when i typing inside textfield?

the code below :

```
  // textField delegate
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.6, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            textField.layer.shadowOpacity = 6
            textField.bounds.size.width += 15
            textField.bounds.size.height += 15
        }, completion: nil)

    }
```

and please how can i fix this issue

thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although "animation is gone" seems unclear to me, `UIView.animate` does not affect the layer of the component.

Also, if the textfield frame has been set by constraints, you should edit the constants of them instead of changing the frame directly.